# Feedback Poles and Zeroes

Tags: control, control-system, feedback

How do I find the frequency of the pole in this transfer function?

It's supposed to be 1kHz, but I am not sure how they got that answer in this [Texas Instruments application note: Switch-mode power converter compensation made easy - SLUP340](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup340/slup340.pdf)

[image: Poles and zeros definition]

[image: Bode plot]

Comment: But you did not show us the circuit?

Comment: Where do they state that it's 1 kHz (it's not in the picture you posted). What has this unknown circuit's link to feedback?

Comment: there is not circuit - they just give the transfer function

Comment: I added the graph they show as well. This is from this application note: https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup340/slup340.pdf

Comment: To find the pole on the graph, simply find freq at which the magnitude is -3dB from the maximum value (0dB in your case). Thus, F_pole is at 1kHz

Comment: Or, when the phase passes through 45 degrees (1st order low pass filter).

Comment: The text of the first picture answers your question of the second picture better than almost any answer we could give. Could you be more specific about your question, what your exact problem is?

Comment: Without the graph, how could you solve the problem algebraically?

Comment: From the transfer function? By inspection. They already give the factorized canonical form \$\omega_p\$ (p = pole, omega = frequency; pole frequency).

Comment: You need to set the denominator to 0 (\$ 1 + \frac{s}{6280} = 0 \$) and solve for s. And you will get that s= - 6280, Thus we have a Pole at 6280 rad/s = 1KHz

Comment: Oh, I see. So they already give me Wp = 1kHz. In general form Wp = -s, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Look here https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Bode/bodeDraw.html?c=1&num=1&den=(s%20%2B%201)%20(s%20%2B%2010)  The denominator is (s +1)(s +10). So if we solve is for s we get (s+1)(s+10) = 0 --> s1 = -1; s2 = -10 Thus we have two poles.

Comment: @RGBEngineer I believe that the critical frequency is found for low-pass, high-pass, and band-pass filters by looking at phase and knowing the filter order, \$n\$. For low-pass, the phase starts at \$0^\circ\$, goes to \$n\cdot +90^\circ\$, and the cross-over is when the phase reaches \$n\cdot +45^\circ\$. For high-pass, the phase starts at \$n\cdot +90^\circ\$, goes to \$0^\circ\$, and the cross-over is when the phase reaches \$n\cdot +45^\circ\$. For band-pass, the phase starts at \$n\cdot +45^\circ\$, goes to \$n\cdot -45^\circ\$, and the cross-over is when the phase reaches \$0^\circ\$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is find the -3 dB point, you can do this by drawing two lines along the frequency magnitude plot:

[image]

#### The -3 dB point is the blue line and the corner frequency